# .Lib file generated instead of .dll file

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS 2013 trying to built an old legacy C/C++ application. The issue which I face is that, once I built the project after applying the settings mentioned below, the output window shows everything as successful & the file generated as K:\DEVELOPMENT\maccat\client\PSCDLL.\DebugNexGen\pscdll.lib.

However I couldn't find any .dll's even after searching the entire Drives(s). Only a static library pscdll.lib is created as the output. The debug log doesn't report anything suspicious except the below warnings:

> LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/pdbtype:sept'; ignored
>   psauto.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to
>   '/SAFESEH' specification
>        Creating library .\DebugNexGen\pscdll.lib and object .\DebugNexGen\pscdll.exp   pscdll.vcxproj ->
>   K:\DEVELOPMENT\maccat\client\PSCDLL.\DebugNexGen\pscdll.dll

Below are my project Settings for the Project: pscdll

**Configuration Properties->General**

Output Directory - .\DebugNextGen\
Target Name - $(ProjectName)
Target Extension - .dll
Configuration Type - Dynamic Library

**Under Linker**

Output File : .\DebugNextGen\pscdll.dll  /* BTW what is the use of this since we already specified this path in General Settings */

I have tried removing the text in the Output File tab (leaving it blank) after specifying the Target extension but the results are same.

One ore observation I found is that during my self troubleshooting steps I was able to generate the .dll file for once (which I am unable to do now) which was considerably smaller in size (compared to the .dll file which was generated previously using some older version of VS) & it was not working when I tried to use it (showing that the dll was either not registered or had some internal errors)

Comment: pscdll.lib contains the symbols of the exported functions. Make sure you use dllexport to export your functions

Comment: Make sure you have _Dynamic Library (.dll)_ set under _General / Configuration Type_.

Comment: How big is created .lib file? Is there a post-build event set? Do you have some antivirus software installed, and what happens with build if you disable it?

Comment: @seccpur - Unfortunately, I don't have the option to modify the code solely for this as this dll was generated properly with some old versions of VS (VS 2006 I think). the newly generated lib seems fine,  The system runs an AVG anti-virus for which I couldn't see a disable option (it's grayed out).

Comment: @Dialecticus - sorry, I don't have any idea on that, since I am not having a valid .lib file to compare with the new one . Its about 78kb in size as opposed to the old .dll file which is of 248kb in size

Comment: You could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to watch all file activity on specified path, and try to make sense of it.